# Full text search search in column that contain multiple world

Tags: sql, full-text-search, contains

I want to use full text search to find in a column the word that begins by for example 'ma'
I used CONTAINS(IDC_NOM,"'firstName*"')  but in the case that I have in a column the name for example : 'ffff mate' it returns this row because the second world begins with 'ma'. I want to search only in the column that the first word begins with 'ma'.

Answer (score 0):

use like query

```
SELECT * FROM Customers
```

WHERE firstNameLIKE '%ma%';

Comment: tankyou for this response , but i dont want to use LIKE the request become so slow , i wanna use full text search

Comment: so you can use  SELECT * FROM Customers where firstname=@firstname

Answer (score 0):

A good way to do that would have been

```
select * from Users
where contains(substring(Name, 0, CHARINDEX(' ', Name)),'user')
```

but contains does not allows any functions in its first parameter. Another way could have been

```
select * from
(
  select substring(Name, 0, CHARINDEX(' ', Name)) as Name
  from Users
) A
where contains(Name,'user')
```

but this also gives error that the column is not full-text indexed, so cannot use contains.

So basically you cannot use contains with conditions on a column as the index is applied to the whole column. I know contains is faster than like operator, so you want to use it but it doesn't accept conditions. The like query with your conditions will be

```
select * from Users
where substring(Name, 0, CHARINDEX(' ', Name)) like '%user%';
```